# Microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0 error on windows 7

Tags: c#, database, oledb

I have folllowing things on my PC

Windows 7 (64bit OS)
Microsoft Office 2003

### Microsoft Visual c# Express 2008

I have two projects on this system. In one project MS Access is connecting though Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 provider, but in second project it gives error, says "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine."

I need some help...

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 2):

You have to compile your C# application to x86. "Any CPU" or "x64" is not an option since the Jet Ole DB driver/provider is not available for 64-bit systems, only for 32-bit.